# Logic for dust template engine

Tags: javascript, dust.js

So i have a dust file which renders certain values to the page on a given input

For instance my dust file would have

```
{Name}
{homeAddress}
{?zip}{zip},&nbsp{/zip}
{state}
```

Now if the user were not to input in the zip value it would skip {zip}, but for some reason it reads the ,&nbsp before reaching the {state}. I am not sure why this is happening, i also checked json value for zip is set to "", if the value is not provided

Comment: Could you post the object you are passing ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, works for me when I experiment here: http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html

{ "Name": "fred",
  "zip": ""
}

Is it possible there is space between the quotes of the zip?

Comment: i checked the value for zip has no spaces between the quotes, at this point i am stumped is there an alternative will using "@eq" be a solution?